# htaccess 301 redirect url with and without path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

im trying to redirect:

from `example.com/shop` to `example.com#shop`

but only if the url is like that, without further child paths,
otherwise if it is like:

```
example.com/shop/mypage
```

i'd like to keep it as it is, so `example.com/shop/mypage`

is this possible via htaccess 301 redirects?

what i tried so far without success is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop #shop [L,R=301,NC,NE]
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /shop/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `^shop` matches any URL path that _begins with_ `shop` - you need to anchor this pattern at the end with a `$`, if you want this to match _only_ `shop`. And the second rule needs to be removed - you want to _keep_ those URLs, so it makes no sense to rewrite them to begin with. And here you would even be creating an endless loop, because you’d be redirecting _from_ `shop/mypage` _to_ `shop/mypage` again.

Comment: @CBroe it works! i also understood how with your explanation, thanks a lot

Comment: @CBroe Please write _answers_ in the answer box - comments are only for clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^shop` matches any URL path that begins with `shop` - you need to anchor this pattern at the end with a `$`, if you want this to match only shop.

And the second rule needs to be removed - you want to keep those URLs, so it makes no sense to rewrite them to begin with. And here you would even be creating an endless loop, because you’d be redirecting from `shop/mypage` to `shop/mypage` again.